# What are the degrees of freedom to consider for a G-test when some cells have expected values of 0?

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio, degrees-of-freedom

Let's say I conduct a survey where people can mention their favorite
color among four options (red, green, blue, yellow).

After collecting the data, I create a contingency table crossing
gender with favorite color, and I end up with the following table (this is completely made up data, my upcoming question is not about this specific dataset, but is more general):

|  | men | women | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 50 | 10 | 3 |
| green | 2 | 25 | 2 |
| blue | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| yellow | 13 | 25 | 8 |

Surprisingly, no one among the respondents chose blue (even if it's a certainty that some people in the population prefer blue). This would make
computing a chi-square statistic not possible (given the division by 0
it would involve), unless dropping the "blue" line and conducting a
chi-square test on the resulting 3x3 table.

However, instead of using a chi-square test, we could use a [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test),
given that the division by 0 is not problematic in this case (it's my
understanding that $0 \cdot ln (\frac{0}{0}) = 0$, but correct me if I'm
wrong).

So (if I'm right) the contribution of each cell from the "blue" row would be
essentially 0 to the G statistic.

But when computing the related p-value attached to this G statistic,
what would be the degrees of freedom to consider here? Would it be
$2\cdot3=6$, or $2\cdot2=4$ ?

I know a test wouldn't be informative in the example I give above, given that the difference between each gender and/or color is really obvious, no need for a test here. But this is a purely theoretical question for my own instruction, not
related to any practical problem to solve (even if I'd be glad to
hear about real-life situations, if any, where this can be a problem to consider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contribution of cells with zero counts is zero in the G-test since each such term is evaluated as 0 in this situation. This is based on the limit of x, which is a standard calculus result.

The contribution of cells with zero counts is zero in the G-test, as the expression for those cells is $( 0 \cdot \ln\left(\frac{0}{0}\right))$, which is treated as 0 in this context. This is based on the limit $( \lim_{x \to 0} x \ln(x) = 0 )$, a standard result in calculus

In your scenario, the degrees of freedom (df) for the G-test are as follows:

With the 'Blue' Category: The degrees of freedom for a G-test in a contingency table are normally calculated as A * B (number of rows1)(number of columns1). If we include the 'blue' category in your situation, this would be 2 x 3 = 6.

If you eliminate the 'blue' category because it has zero counts across all rows, the table effectively becomes a 3x2 table. The degrees of freedom are then 1 x 2 = 2.

In practice, it's a little more complicated:

- Real-World scenarios: Such scenarios can arise in practice, particularly in tiny samples or with infrequent incidents. In these circumstances, it is critical to determine if the zero counts are a function of the sampling technique or an actual absence in the population.
- Statistical Validity: The decision to exclude a category should be carefully evaluated. Excluding a category can be justifiable if there are sufficient reasons to believe that the zero counts  not only are due to sampling variability but also are a real reflection of the population (e.g., that category is impossible to occur).
- Consult with a Statistician: In complex circumstances like this, contact with a statistician is recommended to ensure proper data processing and statistical test interpretation.

In summary, the choice of which df to use in the G-test is determined by whether the 'blue' category is included or excluded. The context of your study, as well as the underlying assumptions concerning the zero counts in the 'blue' group, should inform your choice.

Comment: [-1] (1) "A * B (number of rows1)(number of columns1)" Not sure what A & B are, but you must mean (no. rows - 1) x (no. columns - 1). (2) Eliminating the 'blue category' results in a 3x3 table & hence 4 d.f. for the test, as stated in the q. (3) If 'blue' is not impossible but merely rare, the test statistic still only asymptotically approaches a chi-squared distribution with 6 d.f. - at smaller sample sizes it'll be closer to a chi squared distribution with 4 d.f.

Comment: ... Note that common rules of thumb (e.g. expected counts under the null of at least 5 in four-fifths of cells & at least 1 in all cells) rule out the application of large-sample results in this case. (4) As the total count of 'blue' is sufficient for the marginal probability of 'blue', an analysis that conditions on no-one's having chosen blue is valid regardless of whether 'blue' is considered possible or not (& discards little or no - depending on the sampling scheme - information on independence/homogeneity).